# Could not commit Hibernate transaction

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am new in Hibernate. I am trying to write a method that will insert or update 50 records then commit it & then again continue to insert. I am doing this because if something happened while inserting the last record I want to retain all previous records in database.

This is what I am doing:

```
@Override
    public boolean updateStoreDetails(List<StoreDetailsDTO> storeDetailsDTOs){
        Session session = this.hibernateSessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        int count = 0;
        boolean sessionEnded =false;

        for(StoreDetailsDTO storeDetailsDTOTmp : storeDetailsDTOs){
            if(sessionEnded){//At the very beginning, the transaction remains open dont know why. So  session.getTransaction().begin() causing exception
                session.getTransaction().begin();
                sessionEnded = false;
            }
            session.saveOrUpdate(storeDetailsDTOTmp);
            if ( ++count % 10 == 0 ) {      //If batch size is 50 clear session-level cache & to avoid OutOfMemoryException
                  logger.info("Clearing session after 50 batch size. Total rows inserted/updated till now: "+ count);
                  session.getTransaction().commit();
                  session.flush();
                  session.clear();
                  sessionEnded =true;

            } else if(count == storeDetailsDTOs.size()){
               session.getTransaction().commit();
               session.flush();
               session.clear();
            }
        }
        logger.info("Insertion completed. Total rows inserted/updated: "+ count);
        return true;
    }
```

This is working fine but after the executuion of this method an exception is happening. The return value of this method never returned to the calling method due to this. Can anyone help me? The stacktrace:

```
com.follett.fd.exception.UniversityWithSimilarAdoptionException: Could not commit Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started
    at com.follett.fd.service.impl.FFDServiceImpl.populateLocation(FFDServiceImpl.java:194) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.follett.fd.controller.FFDServiceController.populateLocation(FFDServiceController.java:74) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.follett.fd.controller.FFDServiceController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2f892fae.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:173) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.follett.fd.controller.FFDServiceController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f350f456.populateLocation(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:871) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_25]
```

Comment: FYI This is nothing at all to do with the JPA API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have put `@Transactional` at the class level. I believe this was causing the issue though I am not sure. After removing it I was getting some error while executing : `this.hibernateSessionFactory.getCurrentSession();`. I think I have to set one property for that.

Anyway to achieve what I wanted I modified the method:

```
@Override
    public boolean updateStoreDetails(List<StoreDetailsDTO> storeDetailsDTOs){
        Session session = this.hibernateSessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        int count = 0;
        boolean sessionEnded =false;
        
        for(StoreDetailsDTO storeDetailsDTOTmp : storeDetailsDTOs){         
            session.saveOrUpdate(storeDetailsDTOTmp);
            //session.evict(storeDetailsDTOTmp);
            if ( ++count % 50 == 0 ) {      //If batch size is 50 clear session-level cache & to avoid OutOfMemoryException
                  logger.info("Clearing session after 50 batch size.");               
                  session.flush();
                  session.clear();                
            } 
        }       
        return true;
    }
```

I am calling this method after having 50 records to insert. Please note I have kept the `@Transactional` annotation at class level after modifying the method.

Answer (score 1):

You open session only if `sessionEnded` is `true` but you set it to `true` only after `session.getTransaction().commit()`. Better solution would be to start and end session outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code where you can flush the records into DB after 50 records but committing/rollback all in case of failure which is normally the scenario but If you want to commit 50 records then execute commit after clear.

```
    public void insert(List<T> items) {

    //begin transaction
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        T item = items.get(i);
        session.save(item);
        if (i % 50 == 0) {
            session.flush();
            session.clear();
        }           
    }
    session.flush();
    session.clear();

    //commit transaction
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in the flag check which makes the transaction not to begin. I have made the changes hope this will work.

```
@Override 
public boolean updateStoreDetails(List<StoreDetailsDTO> storeDetailsDTOs)
{ 
Session session = this.hibernateSessionFactory.getCurrentSession(); 
int count = 0; 
boolean sessionEnded =true; for(StoreDetailsDTO storeDetailsDTOTmp : storeDetailsDTOs)
{ 
if(sessionEnded)
{
 session.getTransaction().begin(); sessionEnded = false;
 } session.saveOrUpdate(storeDetailsDTOTmp) ; 
if ( ++count % 10 == 0 ) 
{ 
//If batch size is 50 clear session-level cache & to avoid OutOfMemoryException 
logger.info("Clearing session after 50 batch size. Total rows inserted/updated till now: "+ count);
 session.getTransaction().commit();
 session.flush(); session.clear();
 sessionEnded =true; 
}
 else if(count == storeDetailsDTOs.size()){ 
session.getTransaction().commit();
 session.flush(); 
session.clear(); 
} 
} 
logger.info("Insertion completed. Total rows inserted/updated: "+ count);
 return true;
 }
```

Comment: I have tried this before. At the very beginning, the transaction remains open don't know why. I believe this was die to the @Transactional annotation at the class level. So  session.getTransaction().begin() causing exception at the the very beginning.